# Python2 support in 18.04 LTS

Tags: python, security, lts, patch, support

Considering that python2 is included in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and provides LTS support on those packages. Is Ubuntu going to provide security support for python2 packages by back porting evident security issues from python3 to python2. ?

What kind of support would be provided on python 2 packages?

Comment: I think it'll stay as it is, i.e. the version that releases just before python2 goes EOL. No further updates might be provided neither by Python nor by Ubuntu (like what happened with Java 7)

Answer (score 0):

> Is Ubuntu going to provide security support for python2 packages by back porting evident security issues from python3 to python2. ?

No. There is no back porting from python 3 to python 2 by Ubuntu. If there are  issues the python developers need to fix it in python 2 before we get an update for it. Regardless of security related fixes.

> What kind of support would be provided on python 2 packages?

Python 2.7 will not be maintained past 2020. So we do not get any more updates after that.

All software needs to be python 3. I assume the active Ubuntu releases will be as is but there will be more emphasis on upgrading to a python 3 system.

Straight from Guido van Rossum:

> Let's not play games with semantics. The way I see the situation for 2.7 is that EOL is January 1st, 2020, and there will be no updates, not even source-only security patches, after that date. Support (from the core devs, the PSF, and python.org) stops completely on that date. If you want support for 2.7 beyond that day you will have to pay a commercial vendor. Of course it's open source so people are also welcome to fork it. But the core devs have toiled long enough, and the 2020 EOL date (an extension from the originally annouced 2015 EOL!) was announced with sufficient lead time and fanfare that I don't feel bad about stopping to support it at all.

Comment: [This blog post](https://ubuntu.com/blog/psa-for-ros-users-some-things-to-know-as-python-2-approaches-eol) claims more or less the contrary. What is the source of your information?

Comment: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2018-March/152348.html

Comment: Oh and https://discourse.ros.org/t/some-things-to-know-as-python-2-approaches-eol/11175/6  >:-D